# django-axes not capturing failed login attempt, but captures admin failed attempts fine

Tags: django, authentication

I am using Django-axes, and using the exact same steps described in readme on github. I am able to login and logout fine through django views, but none of the failed login attempts get captured if going throught the main website. None the less, failed login attempts from admin site get captured just fine. I am using the FailedLoginMiddleware, and nothing admin specific. I have double checked all the settings and configs, but I am still failing to find the source of the problem. Please help.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'axes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Here is the projects urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_change 

from qs.forms import ValidatingPasswordChangeForm

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'auth/login.html'}),
    (r'^logout/$', logout, {'redirect_field_name': '/login', 
                            'template_name': 'auth/logged_out.html'}),
    (r'^passw_change/$', password_change, 
                           {'post_change_redirect': '/rage', 
                            'template_name': 'auth/password_change.html',
                            'password_change_form': ValidatingPasswordChangeForm}),

    (r'^passw_reset/$', 'views.rage_password_reset'),
    (r'^passw_reset/done/', 'views.rage_password_reset_done'),
    (r'^passw_reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'views.rage_password_reset_confirm'),
    (r'^passw_reset/complete/$', 'views.rage_password_reset_complete'),

    url(r'^$', 'be.views.main.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Try to debug by putting `print` inside `django-axes > axes > middleware.py > class FailedAuthLoginMiddleware(object): > def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why your config wouldn't work- I use django-axes and my setup is the exact same as yours and it works fine. However, you can force axes to log everything by doing the following:

1. Change `axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware` to `axes.middleware.FailedAdminLoginMiddleware` in your `settings.py`.  (`FailedAuthLoginMiddleware` obviously isn't working for you, so don't use it.)
2. Edit your `urls.conf`:

   ```
   ...
   from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_change
   from axes.decorators import watch_login
   ...
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^login/$', watch_login(login), {'template_name': 'auth/login.html'}),
   ...
   ```

This should force axes to log attempts- and doing so may also shed some light on what the initial issue was.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. Apparently some other app in the project was also calling the login view from django.contrib.auth, and I have no clue why it was interfering with the url I actually wanted to handle the stuff. Anyway. Thanks much, even if it was an indirect pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, userena was capturing the login.  Adding 'watch_login' as described above to the signin URL in userna fixed the problem.