# Django-axes not working with custom login view

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

I have followed the below links before asking this question as it seems like a duplicate, but of no use. So I'm asking again.

[Django login with django-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760023/django-login-with-django-axes)

[django-axes not capturing failed login attempt, but captures admin failed attempts fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889799/django-axes-not-capturing-failed-login-attempt-but-captures-admin-failed-attemp)

The django-axes works fine with the admin site, but it is unable to capture the failed attempts from the user custom login view. My custom view at **'/project/app/views.py'** is as follows:

```
from axes.decorators import watch_login
@watch_login
def user_login(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         username = request.POST.get('username')
         password = request.POST.get('password')
         ......
```

and in **settings.py**, the middleware class I'm using is

> 'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware'

and the other django-axes configuration is as follows:

> AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3
>   AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = 30
>   AXES_LOCKOUT_TEMPLATE = '/templates/app/login.html'

and my **urls.py** is as follows:

```
from axes.decorators import watch_login

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^login/$', watch_login(user_login), {'template_name': 'app/login.html'}),
```

when I try to access the admin page or the user page, I'm getting the following error:

> NameError at /admin/
>
> name 'user_login' is not defined

I even tried changing the middleware class from **'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware'** to **'axes.middleware.FailedAdminLoginMiddleware'** as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889799/django-axes-not-capturing-failed-login-attempt-but-captures-admin-failed-attemp), but now nothing seems to work as it showing the error

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

I think I made the question clear.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A year late, but I hope the question and answer are useful to someone else. I just tried this out with my custom login view, and have pretty much the same setup as you, but django 1.9.6 and django-axes 1.6. I did not wrap the `user_login` url in `watch_login()` because if the view's getting called, logically it's getting logged by the `@watch_login` decorator.

It worked fine - I logged in as several different users and axes created access logs that I could view in the admin interface.

Your `NameError at /admin/` seems to indicate that the error is not with django-axes but with your urls.py - specifically the login line (because that view is getting called when access the admin or user login pages, right?). Did you import your app's views, i.e. `from app import views`? And then you need to ensure the `user_login` view's namespace is explicit:

```
url(r'^login/$', watch_login(views.user_login), {'template_name': 'app/login.html'}),...
```

Comment: Hi, I believe this is how they describe it in the official docs:
https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/